# Geocoding Tweets on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, twitter, geocoding

Would really appreciate any help with my issue. I've been looking at this terrific tutorial by Marcin Dziewulski who integrated recent tweets and twitter user avatars onto a Google Map. Basically he places the users avatar where they last tweeted. I highly recommend checking the tutorial out here:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/13/interactive-google-map/

It all seems to make sense except when it comes down to the actual geocoding of the user. The code works beautifully when the different tweeters are from different cities. However, let's say you wanted to track certain users in one city. They're all geocoded from the center of the city and you can only see one avatar at a time. If you refresh the page, another one will show up, in the exact same spot. This obviously isn't what I want. I assume the problems is in this bit of code:

```
var users = o.twitter.get(), arr = new Array;
        for (i in users){
            var user = users[i];
            $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/show/'+user+'.json?callback=?', function(data) {
                var img = data.profile_image_url,
                    screen_name = data.screen_name;
                geocoder.geocode({ address: data.location }, function(response, status){
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var x = response[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                            y = response[0].geometry.location.lng();
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            icon: img,
                            map: map,
                            title: screen_name,
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)
                        });
```

I think something needs to change in the geocoder.geocode({ address: data.location } bit of code, but not 100% positive. I can't seem to find the solution in the Twitter API documentation either.

My question is basically this...can the code above be altered so that it gathers more precise lat and long. coordinates from where tweets are actually generated and then display them correctly at those locations? In other words, don't just put a tweet from NYC in the middle of NYC, but place the avatar at the EXACT location.

I've tested this with my own tweets, with the the location feature of twitter enabled. I just can't figure this out! Thanks again to anyone who can help!

Best,

Brandon

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the vast majority of tweets are not geocoded but the coords are simply guessed from the user's location settings. If you wanted to display this in an interesting way, consider doing a uniform distribution of "center of city" latlongs. This is what census data map-makers often do when they don't have any more exact positioning data than say a district or a tract.

Comment: I guess I'm not following the idea of "center of city" latlongs? Mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: If the user has turned off geo broadcasting on their twitter client, twitter only has the location that they have specified in their profile. Mine says that I'm in New York. This, wanting to be as helpful as possible, Twitter just identifies that tweet as coming from a generic New York location. This location is either the geographic center of the city or whatever coordinates have been determined representative of the city. If you look on Wikipedia most cities have coordinates even though they are not points. It's all a bit weird. I'm not sure why your phone isn't reporting exact latlongs.

Comment: But what I can't figure out is if the user does have their location enabled on something, say a phone, it still puts their tweet at that 'generic location.' Like I mentioned below, I've passed a get through JSON and I can see the actual coordinates returned from where the user tweeted...super exact coordinates with a lot of decimals. I just can't get those coordinates to carry on to the map and have the avatar show up there.

Comment: Well, it looks like that code is grabbing `location` which is the generic city location of the users. The specific location is encoded in `geo` which is, more often than not nil. You could check for a non nil value for geo and then pass that to the geocoder instead of the location string.

Comment: Ok, that seems to make sense. Got a reference for 'geo?'Where are you getting this information, or, where can I get that information? Is that Google Maps API or Twitter API?

Comment: This page in the api has some info on geo although, it is admittedly not wonderfully documented. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

Answer (score 0):

Unless the tweet was made from a mobile device it's lat/long is going to be where the ISP is registered. If I tweet from my desktop my tweets emanate from the street in front of the capitol here in Nashville. If I use my phone and I allow the twitter app to use my lat/long then that would be different. Trust me, I could instantly use the lat/long data in analysis of twitter streams and I wish it were that simple.

What you could do is add a jitter function that adds random displacement along both the x and y coordinate field to displace the tweets lat/long. Or you could grid it out. If you know how many of them you are getting you can figure out easily the bounding area of your grid and do it like that.

Comment: Both tweets from my phone (with location enabled) and my computer (location enabled) show up at the exact location, the center of the city. It doesn't matter what kind of device I use to make the tweet, I still get the same results. Unfortunately I won't know how many 'tweeters' will be on the map, and they could be moving throughout the day. It would be impossible (I think) to create an offset for every unique person. I've returned (using) JSON the exact coordinates of each tweet. They just don't show up on the map. I don't know how to integrate that kind of function with the above code

Comment: The back and forth with Erik is great. Also look at this page: https://dev.twitter.com/terms/geo-developer-guidelines

Comment: Yeah I looked at both of these pages. Still unsure of what to do!